# How do i Resize my UIView subviews to cover superview like zoom in zoom out?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an uiview A inside another uiview B. A contains many other ui objects like uitableview, uitextfield , buttons, etc. in A uiview I have button for zoom in or out . if user click on zoom in my uiview A covers the uiview B then if he click on zoom out then it will be in previous position for iPad could anyone please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand it sounds like you need to look at UIViewAutoresizingMasks. These define in what way your subviews will scale in relation to their super view. For example

```
[mySubview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingMaskWidth];
```

When the width of mySubview's super view is changed mySubviews width will change at the same factor.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim , you have been very helpful to me.